# Can't connect to PostgreSQL on my local network via Knex/PG, but I can via PSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am running PostgreSQL on a Raspberry Pi on my local network. When I try to connect to it via PSQL from my machine, I am able to get into it, but when I try to connect with the same creds via Knex in my Node.js app, I can't. I get this error:

```
connect EHOSTUNREACH fe80::4f78:a1de:89f0:a342:5432 - Local (:::51422)
Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH fe80::4f78:a1de:89f0:a342:5432 - Local (:::51422)
    at internalConnect (node:net:1066:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (node:internal/async_hooks:464:18)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (node:net:1323:9)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:8)
```

I've got this in my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
host    all             all             fe80::/10               md5
host    all             all             2002::/10               md5
```

Comment: What are the actual connection string/parameters used for each?  Maybe one is using ip4 and one ip6?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting! I named the pi `royal.local`, and that's how I'm hitting it in both psql and the node app, but that would make some sense. Is there a good way see what each is actually pointing to under the hood?

Comment: I confirmed that PSQL is using IPv6, and when I put that IP in the node-pg connection string, it doesn't work.